# return statement doesnt return anything in python recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, return

The methods below look in a string to find if it has any python methods.

```
def there_is_a_call( string ): 
    return string.find('(') > -1

def find_and_remove_functions( string , found_functions ): 
    if not there_is_a_call( string ):
        print( found_functions )
        return found_functions
    else: 
        function_end    = string.find('(')
        function_string = string[:function_end][::-1]
        if function_string.find('.') > -1 : 
            index = function_string.find('.')
        elif function_string.find(' ') > -1: 
            index = function_string.find(' ')
        else:
            index = len(function_string) - 1 
        func_name       = function_string[ : index + 1 ][::-1] + '()'
        new_list = found_functions 
        new_list.append( func_name )
        find_and_remove_functions( string[ function_end + 1: ], found_functions )
```

So I try to see if it works and then this happens;

```
>>>> a = find_and_remove_functions( 'func() and some more()' , [] )
['func()', ' more()']
>>>> print(a)
None
```

Why is the return statement not returning anything while the `found_functions` do get printed?

Comment: The `return` statement _is_ returning something… but that's only executed if the `if` is true. Otherwise, you're running the other code, which doesn't `return` anything. it does recursively call the function, but it doesn't do anything with the result of that recursive call. Usually, the last line in the recursive case is a `return` that returns the value of the recursive call, or an expression built around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
find_and_remove_functions( string[ function_end + 1: ], found_functions )
```

should be

```
return find_and_remove_functions( string[ function_end + 1: ], found_functions )
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more explanation here.

`a = find_and_remove_functions( 'func() and some more()' , [] )` prints a list because there is a line `print( found_functions )` being executed.

`a` is assigned to the result of `find_and_remove_functions` and, since the function returns nothing after the set of recursive calls (see your `else` part doesn't have a `return`), it is assigned to `None`.

Here's a simple example of what is happening:

```
>>> def test():
...     print "test"
... 
>>> a = test()
test
>>> print(a)
None
>>> a is None
True
```

Comment: You need to explain why calling `find_and_remove_functions` returns nothing. After all, the base has a `return` in it. It's just that the recursive case doesn't `return` what it gets back from the base case. So, the OP needs to do what karthikr's answer suggests.

Comment: @abarnert sure, updated the answer. Completely agree that the OP should do what karthikr suggested. Thanks!